# Connecting industrial camera to Ubuntu. I am getting images of lower resolution than I should

Tags: linux, usb, hdmi, camera

**Question**.
Is it possible to get 48 mp picture from Panasonic me2022 48 mp industrial camera sensor using usb2.0 cabel? How can solve this issue?

**The camera**
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32803731419.html

**My attempt**.
I tried to connect the camera using hdmi cabel to monitor, and it worrked, picture looked like 48 mp. I also tried to connect it with usb2.0 cable to my pc. I am using Ubuntu. I tried Cheess and VLC programs. These programs detected the camera, and it was possible to see picture. Unfourtunatly picture had much lower resolution (~3mp) than 48mp.
I also tried connecting the camera to the PC using HDMI cabel with noo success. I had read that usually laptops do not support hdmi input.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: `connecting the camera to the PC using HDMI cabel` to a HDMI capture device, or did you try connecting the cameras HDMI **output** to the PC's HDMI **output** ?

Comment: `picture looked like 48 mp` how? an 4K monitor only has 8 million pixels? `~3mp` so, are you using a 2K monitor perhaps?

Comment: Can you provide the exact model of the camera. It not appear on Panasonic site for industrial cameras.

Comment: I wonder if its outputting a 'degraded' image since USB 2.0 might have a lot less bandwidth.   48MP (which I assume is 8064 x 6048  )is far beyond even most displays, and most capture devices are going to have trouble with it too

Comment: About the model of camera. Just type in aliexpress 48mp 4k microscope camera. It is a c-mount camera.

Comment: @AlexAlex its really not appropriate to ask us to go looking in Aliexpress and not particularly helpful either - there are a plethera of results that come up for many different products.

Comment: Assuming that it is like https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000052074925.html it is not designed to output 4k to a PC - it says 1920*1080 @ 60FPS for USB.  If you want to capture 4k through HDMI you will need to get an HDMI capture device that can capture at 4k (Not sure where you would find this.  I had a look at Aliexpress and it seems most of the devices there claim 4k, but only output 1920x1080.

Comment: NOT RECOMMENDATIONS -  https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4001295412499.html appears to capture 4k (but only at 30 hz). So does https://www.startech.com/en-us/audio-video-products/4k30-hdmi-capture.  https://www.elgato.com/us/en/p/game-capture-4k60-pro appears to be a PCI card which will capture at up to 60 hz if you have a desktop.  (Note that I've not even considered the Linux compatibility - only looked at the hardware)

Comment: Sorry. It was no possible to copy link trough my phone. I will post links later, when I will be able to use computer.

Comment: Can you set the camera to a slower frame rate? *If* the specimen is preserved, rather than live, frame rate should not matter in photomicrography.

Comment: No, I can't set camera to a lower frame rate.

Answer (score 1):

The camera you specify has (according to the specs) a 48 megapixel sensor.

On the HDMI output, it produces 1920*1080 at 60F/S, which is substantially lower than the 8064 x 6048 that is suggested.

If you want to store the video, you will get 4K(25fps) 2K(30fps) 1080P(60fps) 720P(60fps). That is even lower than the directly connected HDMI to monitor cable.

So basically: the video specs that you expect are not supported by this camera.

The specs also suggest that you can take a single picture (so not a video) at 8000X6000/38M.